# Unique_Ptrs Syntax {}

Tags: c++, pointers, syntax, unique-ptr

I am writing an Entity Component System based off a tutorial for making a game that I am following.

Currently, the function to add an entity of class "Entity" to an "entities" vector goes like:

```
Entity& addEntity() { 
        Entity* e = new Entity(); 
        std::unique_ptr<Entity> uPtr{ e }; 
        entities.emplace_back(std::move(uPtr)); 
        return *e; 
    }
```

The code is working properly as per the tutorial. However, I am unsure about the actual syntax of Unique_ptr in line:

```
std::unique_ptr<Entity> uPtr{ e };
```

What is actually happening inside the {} braces? As I understand it, I'm assigning my uPtr unique pointer to the value of the pointer e? I would really appreciate an explanation regarding the unique_ptr syntax, especially with the curly braces.

Thanks.

Comment: (2) in: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement creates an instance of unique_ptr using the single-argument constructor. In this case, it is equivalent to the older style `std::unique_ptr<Entity> uPtr(e)`. This reflects the new uniform braced initialization syntax available since C++11.

More details: https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Braced_Initializer_List